# Inequality on Hilbert Space

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, hilbert-spaces

The problem is a sort of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:

> Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in a Hilbert Space $H$, and $(c_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in l^2(\mathbb{N}).$ Let also $F$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}.$
>
> We know that $\exists C>0$ such that for every $x\in H$ we have the property $\sum_n |(x_n,x)|^2\le C\|x\|^2.$
>
> Prove that $$\big\|\sum_{n\in F}c_nx_n\big\|^2\leq \sup_{y\in H, \|y\|=1} \big(\sum _{n\in F}c_n^2\big)\big(\sum_{n\in F}|(y,x_n)|^2\big),$$
> where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the scalar product.

This is quite similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240001/inequality-in-a-hilbert-space), but actually seems to be its inverse.

The right term reminds a lot of an operator norm but I couldn't define any function that could be useful for the problem.
Also, splitting the left term into scalar products leads to some matrix-connected calculation that didn't seem to be useful.

Comment: Did you try using Young's inequality?

Comment: Honestly not, which version of it should be useful?

Comment: Sorry man, I underestimated the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: for any $y\in H$, consider
$$
\Big(y,\sum_{n\in F}c_n x_n\Big)=\sum_{n\in F}c_n(y,x_n).
$$
Apply the C-S to the right hand side and take the supremum over $y$ in the unit ball.